# Subrepresentation iff there exists a $G$-invariant subspace?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I am trying to convince myself that the statement in the title is true as my textbook only goes in "one direction".

In particular, let $T$ be a representation of a group $G$ on a vector space $V$. It was shown that any $G$-invariant subspace $W$ induces a subrepresentation $T_W$ of $G$ on $W$. My question is if these are the only subrepresentations which can exist. Put differently, can there be a subrepresentation not obtainable in this way from a $G$-invariant subspace? My instinct is to say no, since for any subrepresentation $T_W$ of $T$ we have by definition of a subrepresentation that $T_W(g)$ is an automorphism of $W$ for each $g$, and therefore $W$ is $G$-invariant subspace of $V$, but I wanted to check as it's a lot of definitions to unravel and I am self-studying.

Comment: This is true.${}$

Comment: Thank you! @KentaS

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: @Shaun Szekeres's *A Course in Modern Mathematical Physics*.